# Dijkstra's algorithm running time with Array

Tags: algorithm, big-o, dijkstra

in wikipedia they state under the Heading: "running time" for Dijstras algorithm is

O(|V|^2  + |E|*decreaseKey) = O(|V|)

[Dijkstra's_algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm)

This is my first time analyzing time complexity for an algoritm, but in my opinion it should be:

- Outerloop (while Q is not empty) will take O(|v|) time
- Findmin in an array should take O(|v| )
- Once Min is found then examine all neighbors which can take O(|E|)
- then updating they keys for these neigbors is done in constant time C

so we will have

O(V)*( O(|V|) + O(|E|)*C  ) = O(|V|^2 + O(|V|*|E|* C) ) = O(|V|^2)

my question is about the term:

O(|V|*|E|*C)

In Wikipedia they don't even bother the  |V| factor at all why? is my analysis wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "bothering the |V| factor", but `|V|*|E|` is inaccurate. Each edge is only visited at most twice (when each of its endpoints are visited), so `2*|E|` is more accurate, which is just `O(|E|)`. `|E|` in a simple graph is at most the number of vertices in the complete graph of `|V|` vertices, which is `(|V|^2 -  |V|)/2 = O(|V|^2)`.

Answer (score 2):

The issue in your logic is here:

> Once Min is found then examine all neighbors which can take O(|E|)

A single node can only have O(|V|) neighbours, not O(|E|). E is *all* the edges in the graph.

Comment: ok but how do they come to this formula:    "for any implementation for the vertex set the running time is in"  O(|E|*T_{dk} + |V|*T_{em} )  where em = extract minimum and dk = decrease key.  I get the fact that  T_{em} is  O(|V|) (when using array ), but why and where does the |E| come from? @Ryan